# Newcomer at Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I think it will become readily apparent that i have absolutely zilch programming experience as I am currently going out my mind with a problem i am having trying to get my first arduino uno project off the ground. I am simply attempting to acquire the necessary libraries including a TimeLib.h library file, but however i seemingly cant even figure out how exactly to complete that very simple first step. I am giving it a serious go trying to break into this interesting field and would greatly appreciate any advice anyone could generously provide.
With regards,

Newcomer

Comment: Please share your code attempts so we can see where you may be going wrong.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - if you read your own question you will see you have given us no details at all. Posting your code, plus any error messages, would be a good start.

Comment: OP seems to be asking for advice about how to start. Since they haven't gotten farther than including a header they probably have no code worth showing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. If you would like to edit your question to be more specific and narrow in scope I'm sure we can help you. For example: "How do I find and install the library that contains the file TimeLib.h?"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Arduino IDE then you first need to include the library then you can put `#include <TimeLib.h>` at the top of your sketches.

There is plenty of documentation online about how to use Arduino. To solve your immediate problem I would go here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries